# How do I fix my display driver

Tags: windows, laptop, asus-laptop

My display for my laptop is flickering until on top of the screen (almost covering my laptops screen basically) when I put it on 144hz but if I put it on 60hz it disappears and I have a second monitor inorder for me to use my laptop.

I attempt to fixed this display problem for my laptop by following the steps provided by the microsoft support which lead me to turning on my safe mode. Now, my laptop is stuck on 144hz which has a display problem and I'm unable to use my laptop since I can't see anything on my screen and can't further unable safe mode.

Is there anyway to fix this? Or is it impossible to fix it? If possible, is there anyway to undo safe mode?

- My laptop is a ASUS TUF GAMING FA5
- GPU is AMD Ryzen 7-4800H 2.9GHZ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried simply powering off the machine to get out of safe mode?

Comment: I have and its still stuck on safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

If stuck in Safe mode and can't see the screen,
you will need to boot from the Windows boot media.

Boot to the Command Prompt (CMD) and enter the command that works for you:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
```